# What does a '.' means in output?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So, I was solving a question which basically has the following code:

```
int rez,arr[10000],n,l,diff;
float f;
int main (void)
{
    cin>>n>>l;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    sort(arr,arr+n);
    rez = 2*max(arr[0],l-arr[n-1]);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n-1; i++ )
    {
        rez = max(rez, arr[i+1]-arr[i]);
    }
    f = rez/2.0;
    printf("%.10f\n",f);
    return 0;
}
```

The above is the code for the following problem:

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/492/B

Logic: Sort lanterns in non-decreasing order. Then we need to find maximal distance between two neighbour lanterns, let it be maxdist. Also we need to consider street bounds and count distances from outside lanterns to street bounds, it will be (a[0] - 0) and (l - a[n - 1]). The answer will be max(maxdist / 2, max(a[0] - 0, l - a[n - 1]))

Now, the above code gives a WA (Wrong answer) but on modifying the last statement to,

`printf("%.10f\n",rez/2.);` (and removing f), I get Accepted. What does this `.` mean and why does it give a WA when I use an extra variable `f`?

Comment: What answer does your original code give? What is the correct answer?

Comment: The empty dot in `2.` simply means `2.0`. And the reason it might not work with your version might be that `f` is a `float` while if you use the expression directly in the `printf` call it's a `double`.

Comment: Also, which `.` are you referring to? I see one in `"%.10f"` and one in `rez/2.` in the line you are asking about.

Comment: I am talking about the one in `rez/2.`

Comment: @Joachim, so I might be getting a Wrong answer in my version because the actual size might be exceeding the capacity of a float?

Comment: @Elliot  Not size, but *precision*. The answer might need more decimals than `float` is able to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of`.`in both statement is as follow-

Let us take an example `int a=4; float c;` If we write `c=a/3;`then`printf("%f",c);`will give`1.000000`(precise to six decimal place) , if you write`printf("%.10f",c);` then it will give`1.0000000000`(precise to ten decimal place) , that means writing`.`in printf will give significance digit precise to number written after`.` And if we write `c=a/3.0`this means we tell compiler to divide `int by float`and here implict conversion(or type promotion) takes place and complier treat`int a as float`and give output`1.333333`. So we can achieve precise answer upto reqiured significant digit doing this.